# Sylvester's dialectic method

Tags: polynomials

Nevermind. I have got it

I am willing to study Sylvester's Dialectic Method regarding polynomial. Today in one book I have come to know about it but could not find it. In MSE I tried my best to find it but in vain.

Can anyone suggest me some links on it ?

Comment: Try searching instead for references to Sylvester's **dialytic** method.

Comment: Thank you so much (infinitely many :-) ) My problem is solved

Comment: @CalumGilhooley For the sake of moving this question off the unanswered list, would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment reposted as answer: try searching instead for references to Sylvester's **dialytic** method.